# Why does getArguments().getParcelable(key) behave differently in local test device vs production release?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, parcelable

In my `MainActivity` I call this code to change to a new fragment, I pass a bundle with parcelable object, `itemModel` to the fragment:

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    bundle.putParcelable(ItemModel.ParcelableKey, itemModel);
    fragment = new AppFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

In the fragment, I receive the parcel back like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mItemModel = getArguments().getParcelable(ItemModel.ParcelableKey);
    //....other code.....
}
```

When I test it locally, the code works fine on my test device, `mItemModel` is able to be retrieved back properly, however, I have integrated crash report system into the app (Crashlytics), and the report states a log like this on a release:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.temp.test/com.temp.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at android.os.Parcel.readStringArray(Parcel.java:931)
       at com.temp.test.data.ItemModel.<init>(ItemModel.java:478)
       at com.temp.test.data.ItemModel.<init>(ItemModel.java:23)
       at com.temp.test.data.ItemModel$1.createFromParcel(ItemModel.java:445)
       at com.temp.test.data.ItemModel$1.createFromParcel(ItemModel.java:443)
       at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2103)
       at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1965)
       at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2226)
       at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
       at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:1165)
       at com.temp.test.fragments.AppFragment.onCreateView(AppFragment.java:98)
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveTo## Heading ##State(FragmentManager.java:1035)
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1017)
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1804)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

`at com.temp.test.fragments.AppFragment.onCreateView(AppFragment.java:98)` <-- This error line leads to this line in the source code:

```
mItemModel = getArguments().getParcelable(ItemModel.ParcelableKey);
```

It is very strange because it works well in my local device. So I dived a little deeper into `Bundle`'s source code, I noticed that in `unparcel()`, it has a checking like this at the beginning:

```
synchronized void unparcel() {

    if (mParcelledData == null) {
        if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "unparcel " + Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(this)) + ": no parcelled data");
        return;
    }
    //....other code.....
}
```

The strange thing is that `mParcelledData` should be `null` in my case, because I created `Bundle` like this `Bundle bundle = new Bundle();` as shown in my code snippet above, so in my case it should be using `mMap` instead of `mParcelledData`.

Question: what are the possible cases that `getArguments()` in `fragment's onCreateView()` will return a `Bundle` with non-null `mParcelledData`?

OR

In what cases that `mItemModel = getArguments().getParcelable(ItemModel.ParcelableKey);` will perform differently in my local test device vs production release for end user?

Comment: problem is with `ItemModel` class ... `at com.temp.test.data.ItemModel.<init>(ItemModel.java:478)
       at com.temp.test.data.ItemModel.<init>(ItemModel.java:23)`

Comment: Ya, that is the place that caused it to crash, but it shouldn't go down that path that cause it to crash from `unparcel()`.